# Debugging T4 Template in VS 2010 Crashes IDE

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, t4

I'm trying to debug a slightly-modified version of the *ADO.NET POCO Entity Generator* template using the directions [Oleg Sych published](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-debugging-code-generation-files/) a few years back.  I modified the *DbgJITDebugLaunchSetting* key as recommended.

I get a dialog indicating that a user-defined breakpoint has been hit.  However, rather than being presented with the option to debug with a new instance of VS 2010, the original instance of VS 2010 just crashes and auto-restarts.

Is it possible to debug T4 templates with VS 2010?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

in Visual Studio 2010 you need to call Debugger.Launch() before Debugger.Break().

Comment: That did it as far as launching a new debugger instance, but now I get No Source Available for Call stack location: *13gocwvx!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating9936422A04D1D8AC631D9CB3A394DD16.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() + 0x34 bytes.*  Any thoughts?

Comment: Accepting because it was partially correct, but I still get the above error.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); or Break(), attach the debugger manually.

1. In a second instance of vs2010,
   open the T4 template you want to
   debug (just the .tt file is fine)
2. Go to Debug -> Attach to Process and find the original devenv.exe
   process
3. Add a regular breakpoint
   (red ball) to the place you want to
   start the debug (in the second
   vs2010 still)
4. Go to the original
   vs2010, save the .tt file and...
   bingo! The second instance of vs2010
   will debug your template.

Answer (score 3):

Final solution which works for me:

regedit:

Key (x86 systems): `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework`

Key (x64 systems): `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework`

value: `DbgJITDebugLaunchSetting`

data: `0x2`

tt template:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true"  #>
<# System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); #>
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need debug=true:

<@#template debug="true" #>
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
Debugger.Break();

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126338.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To add to andrecarlucci's solution, if you save the file, you will be prompted to reload it in the second instance of Visual Studio before you can debug it. If you don't need to make further changes but need to debug it multiple times, you don't have to save every time in order to break into the code. You can simply click the Transform All Templates button on the Solution Explorer toolbar in the original instance of Visual Studio.